# Microsoft OracleClient Provider and Positional Parameters Binding

Tags: oracle, ado.net, parameters

Does anyone know how to get the Microsoft OracleClient Provider to support binding parameters by position, currently it does that only by Name and there does not seem to be any option to specify to use positional parameters. I know that Oracle's ODP.NET supports positional parameters, but i want this in Microsoft's provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe OracleClient via Microsoft does not unfortunately which has bit me on several occasions.  As you likely are aware, OracleClient has been deprecated as of .net 4.0 so if this is a necessity you will likely need to use a third party ADO.net data provider for to accomplish this.

Comment: I ended up using Oracle's ODP.Net Provider, but it was an additional effort for getting it installed on all servers